# Need to fetch data from a really messed up mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Table 1:

```
id  |  video_id  | group_id  |  img
=======================================
1   |  1         | 1         |  
2   |  2         | 1         | abc.png 
3   |  3         | 2         | bef.png 
4   |  4         | 3         | dca.png
5   |  5         | 1         |  
6   |  6         | 2         |  
7   |  8         | 1         |
```

Table 2:-

```
video_id  | week  |  count  |  type
===================================
1         | 2     |  2      |  0
2         | 2     |  1      |  1
1         | 3     |  5      |  0
1         | 3     |  3      |  1
3         | 3     |  4      |  0
1         | 3     |  1      |  0
```

Now I know this structure is messed up and needs to be normalized, but as I don't have modification rights to it, I am stuck with this. So please bear with me.

As you can see, the first table stores multiple videos within a group, and only one video in each group can have an associated image.
The second table stores the type and count of video views on a per week basis.

Now I need a mysql query to fetch SUM of counts, the video id, and the image present against the group id of this video for a particular week. The problem is, the image is stored against ONE video of a group, which may or may not have the highest sum views, but still the query will need to fetch the image against whichever video has the image for that group along with the video id and other info of the video with the max view count.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing really, currently I am simply fetching the group id and video id in a single query in my php code, and then running another query on that group id to fetch the image. But my client wants it to be done with a single query, and I have no idea how to do it that way

Comment: I think you should fix the problem instead of working around the problem? Tell that to your client.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, leaving the messy database structure out of this, what do you mean with this:

> but still the query will need to fetch the image against whichever
>   video has the image for that group

Where exactly do you need the group for? Something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT table2.video_id, SUM(table2.count), table1.group_id, table1.img FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.video_id = table1.video_id
GROUP BY table2.video_id;
```

This will select the video id, the total amount of counts (over all weeks), the group_id and the image which belongs to that video. No group_id in any checks involved though, as I am not sure what you want with it.

Apart from this I agree on what the others suggest as well: try to get better structured tables!

EDIT: if you need to get the image and the groupid together you can run the following query, but it will only pick the first img which is not empty. So you have to be sure that the relation between group_id and set img is 1:1, or else it might mess up.

Updated query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT table1.group_id,
          (SELECT tbl.img FROM table1 tbl WHERE tbl.group_id = table1.group_id AND img IS NOT NULL /*or whatever the empty value for img is*/ LIMIT 1) AS img,
          table2.video_id,
          SUM(table2.count) AS totalviews
    FROM table2 
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.video_id = table1.video_id 
    GROUP BY table1.group_id, table2.video_id) 
    AS tmp
WHERE totalviews = (SELECT SUM(tbl2.count) FROM table2 AS tbl2 WHERE tbl2.video_id = tmp.video_id)
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Comment: I think the image belongs to the group. So if you get video_Id 1 he needs the second row img in the first table.

Comment: Do I understand correct that what you actually want is this: 
group_id -> image with that group -> for this group all the video id's -> per video the total amount of views?

Comment: The edited answer is closer, but the result list still contains all video ids. But I need it to fetch the only the video_id with Maximum value for the sum of it's count property + the associated group id + the image of that group. So I guess I will need to nest all this in yet another subquery, right?

Comment: Ok, then you can use the earlier stated query as a preparation of the data (put it in a subquery) and filter the final results out of it. See updated answer. It's not very pretty, but with the current database structure there's not a lot we can do. ;-)